# Conda entry_points configuration

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to create a conda package from my sources but I get the stuck with the `build/entry_points` part of the `meta.yaml` configuration file.

Explanations:

Here is my `setup.py` file  which works correctly with `pip` :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from codecs import open
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='myproject',
    version='1.1.0',
    description='My project',
    long_description=long_description,
    url='',
    author='Me',
    author_email='me@me.com',
    license='',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
        #todo License::
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Topic :: Database :: Front-Ends',
        'Topic :: Adaptive Technologies',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Bio-Informatics',
        'Topic :: Software Development',
    ],
    keywords='workflow manager python object-oriented reproducible science database framework',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['log', 'doc', '*.test.*', 'soutenance', 'rapport']),
    install_requires=required,
    package_data={},
    data_files=[],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts':['wopmars=src.main.fr.tagc.wopmars.wopmars:main']
    }
)
```

Here is my `meta.yaml` file in conda recipe.

```
package:
  name: wopmars
  version: "1.1.0"

build:
  entry_points:
    - wopmars = src.main.fr.tagc.wopmars.wopmars:main

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
```

The file `build.sh` is present too and contains `$PYTHON setup.py install`.

Then I build the conda package:

```
(test_wop) luc@everest:~/Documents/WORK/wopmars$ conda build .
Removing old build environment
BUILD START: wopmars-1.1.0-py35_0
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    openssl:    1.0.2h-1     
    pip:        8.1.2-py35_0 
    python:     3.5.2-0      
    readline:   6.2-2        
    setuptools: 23.0.0-py35_0
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0     
    tk:         8.5.18-0     
    wheel:      0.29.0-py35_0
    xz:         5.2.2-0      
    zlib:       1.2.8-3      

Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|#######################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%
Package: wopmars-1.1.0-py35_0
source tree in: /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/conda-bld/work/pyinstrument-0.13.1
+ source activate /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
++ [[ -n 4.3.42(1)-release ]]
++ _SCRIPT_LOCATION=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/activate
++ SHELL=bash
+++ dirname /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/activate
++ _CONDA_DIR=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin
++ '[' 1 -gt 1 ']'
++ case "$(uname -s)" in
+++ uname -s
++ EXT=
++ [[ -n 4.3.42(1)-release ]]
+++ basename /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/conda-bld/work/pyinstrument-0.13.1/conda_build.sh
++ [[ conda_build.sh == \a\c\t\i\v\a\t\e ]]
++ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
++ args=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
++ /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/conda ..checkenv bash /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
++ ((  0 != 0  ))
++ source /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/deactivate
+++ [[ -n 4.3.42(1)-release ]]
+++ _SCRIPT_LOCATION=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/deactivate
+++ SHELL=bash
++++ dirname /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/deactivate
+++ _CONDA_DIR=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin
+++ case "$(uname -s)" in
++++ uname -s
+++ EXT=
+++ [[ 1 > 0 ]]
+++ key=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
+++ case $key in
+++ shift
+++ [[ 0 > 0 ]]
+++ [[ -n 4.3.42(1)-release ]]
++++ basename /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/conda-bld/work/pyinstrument-0.13.1/conda_build.sh
+++ [[ conda_build.sh == \d\e\a\c\t\i\v\a\t\e ]]
+++ [[ -z '' ]]
+++ [[ -n 4.3.42(1)-release ]]
++++ basename /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/conda-bld/work/pyinstrument-0.13.1/conda_build.sh
+++ [[ conda_build.sh == \d\e\a\c\t\i\v\a\t\e ]]
+++ return 0
+++ /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/conda ..activate bash /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
++ _NEW_PART=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin
++ ((  0 == 0  ))
++ export CONDA_PATH_BACKUP=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/test_wop/bin:/home/luc/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/bin:/home/luc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ CONDA_PATH_BACKUP=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/test_wop/bin:/home/luc/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/bin:/home/luc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ export CONDA_PS1_BACKUP=
++ CONDA_PS1_BACKUP=
++ export PATH=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/test_wop/bin:/home/luc/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/bin:/home/luc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ PATH=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/test_wop/bin:/home/luc/bin:/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/bin:/home/luc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
++ [[ '' == */* ]]
++ export CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
++ CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
++ firstpath=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin
+++ echo /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin
+++ sed 's|/bin$||'
++ export CONDA_PREFIX=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
+++ /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/conda ..changeps1
++ '[' 1 = 1 ']'
+++ grep -q CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
++ export 'PS1=(/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build) '
++ PS1='(/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build) '
++ _CONDA_D=/home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/etc/conda/activate.d
++ [[ -d /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/etc/conda/activate.d ]]
++ unset CONDA_PATH
++ [[ -n 4.3.42(1)-release ]]
++ hash -r
+ /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin/python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dependency_links to pyinstrument.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing pyinstrument.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pyinstrument.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing entry points to pyinstrument.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'pyinstrument.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'pyinstrument.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument
copying build/lib/pyinstrument/profiler.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument/resources
copying build/lib/pyinstrument/resources/profile.js -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument/resources
copying build/lib/pyinstrument/resources/jquery-1.11.0.min.js -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument/resources
copying build/lib/pyinstrument/resources/style.css -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument/resources
copying build/lib/pyinstrument/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument
copying build/lib/pyinstrument/__main__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument
copying build/lib/pyinstrument/middleware.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument/profiler.py to profiler.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument/__main__.py to __main__.cpython-35.pyc
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pyinstrument/middleware.py to middleware.cpython-35.pyc
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyinstrument.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyinstrument.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyinstrument.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyinstrument.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyinstrument.egg-info/not-zip-safe -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying pyinstrument.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
creating 'dist/pyinstrument-0.13.1-py3.5.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing pyinstrument-0.13.1-py3.5.egg
creating /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyinstrument-0.13.1-py3.5.egg
Extracting pyinstrument-0.13.1-py3.5.egg to /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Adding pyinstrument 0.13.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pyinstrument script to /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/bin

Installed /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyinstrument-0.13.1-py3.5.egg
Processing dependencies for pyinstrument==0.13.1
Finished processing dependencies for pyinstrument==0.13.1
found egg dir: /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyinstrument-0.13.1-py3.5.egg
number of files: 19
Fixing permissions
Detected hard-coded path in text file bin/pyinstrument
Detected hard-coded path in text file bin/wopmars
Fixing permissions
BUILD END: wopmars-1.1.0-py35_0
Nothing to test for: wopmars-1.1.0-py35_0
# If you want to upload this package to anaconda.org later, type:
#
# $ anaconda upload /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/conda-bld/linux-64/wopmars-1.1.0-py35_0.tar.bz2
#
# To have conda build upload to anaconda.org automatically, use
# $ conda config --set anaconda_upload yes
```

And here starts the issue: I don't understand why this outputs that much informations about the `pyinstrument` package and that few about my package, `wopmars` (the `pyinstrument` package have been used during the tutorial of `conda`)

But I keep going and I try to install `wopmars`:

```
(test_wop) luc@everest:~/Documents/WORK/wopmars$ conda install --use-local wopmars
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/test_wop:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    wopmars: 1.1.0-py35_0 local

Proceed ([y]/n)? 

Linking packages ...
[      COMPLETE      ]|#######################################################################################################################################################################################| 100%
```

Everything seems to be ok IMO BUT:

```
(test_wop) luc@everest:~/Documents/WORK/wopmars$ wopmars
bash: /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/test_wop/bin/wopmars: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

(cannot find this type of file or directory)

I have probably missed something, but I cannot figure out what is the problem here.

Please, how do you specify `entry_points` of a project in a `conda` package?

Answer (score 3):

Conda is packaging `pyinstruments` instead of your project `wopmars` as shown in the build log (line starting by *source tree*):

```
(...)
Package: wopmars-1.1.0-py35_0
source tree in: /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/conda-bld/work/pyinstrument-0.13.1
+ source activate /home/luc/bin/anaconda3/envs/_build
(...)
```

In your `meta.yaml` try adding a [source section](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/building/meta-yaml.html#source-section). Assuming your `meta.yaml` is in the same directory as your Python source files, you could use:

```
source:
    path: .
```